# Multiple foreign keys on same table column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I got multiples table as example:

- 3 table: Alarm1,Alarm2 ,Alarm3.
- 1 table: AlarmLog
- 1 table: Users
- 1 table: TypeAlarm

Alarms table (id as PK identity , others column which are different each tables)

AlarmLog table (id as PK identity, AlarmID, UserID, TypeAlarmID)

The id of the table alarm1,alarm2 and alarm3 are log in alarmLog(id,AlarmID , UserID,TypeAlarmID)

It's is possible to add a foreign key on the AlarmLog table which reference on each of the alarmID of the multiple alarms table?

The problem is pretty sample, this TSQL work fine as example and return in this case of alarm1 table:

```
Select  * From AlarmLog
Inner join alarm1 on AlarmLog.AlarmID = alarm1.id
Inner join Users on Users.id = AlarmLog.UserID
Inner Join TypeAlarm on TypeAlarm.id = AlarmLog.TypeAlarmID
```

But I want to remove the stored procedure like the T-SQL above and get it from the Entity Framework.

Which so simple if you got foreign key!

Comment: Why do you have three tables for alarms, instead of just one?  That is the root cause of your problem.

Comment: the tables are full of data and i can't remake it...

Comment: It would take work to remake it, it can be done. 1) Stop writing to two of the tables, 2) move the data from those tables to the one you decide to keep. I agree with @GordonLinoff's assessment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, It is not possible to have one column point toward three other tables. The foreign key will create a strong coherency check and the data would require to exist in the three tables.

The only solution would be to use triggers on Insert and Delete statements to do the required coherency checks and cascades automatically, without a foreign key.

Please refer to:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: I'll take a look for the trigger, that could be helpful.